# Op-amp input impedance datasheet specification

Tags: operational-amplifier, input-impedance

Some op-amp datasheets specify both the differential and common-mode input impedance:

[image: LME49723]

[image: OPA1664]

while others just specify "input resistance":

[image: NE5532]

[image: NJM2068]

I've always assumed that if the datasheet only shows one value, it's the same as the *differential* input impedance, but I want to make sure.

Especially because TI's "[Understanding Operational Amplifier Specifications](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa011/sloa011.pdf)" distinguishes between the two terms:

> - ri Input resistance: The resistance between the input terminals with either input grounded.
> - rid Differential input resistance: The small-signal resistance between two ungrounded input terminals.

Comment: I would guess that 300 kΩ typical would almost have to be differential input. Even the 741 has 2 MΩ typical common mode input resistance.

Comment: I don't think there is a generic answer to this unfortunately. Link a DS that appears to be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

For CMOS opamps, you are measuring GigaOhms for either, perhaps dominated by the leakage of ESD structures which degrades as temperature rises.

For bipolar, the common-mode at DC will be proportional to the stiffness of the tail current source of the input diffpair. For AC, the various capacitances affect that Zin.

For bipolar, the differential depends on beta * reac or beta * 1/gm, at DC

For bipolar at AC, the Miller effect will become a killer as the diffpair
moves into its linear region.

For example, examine datasheet of the UA715 opamp. Look at the schematic.

The input diffpair has "cascode" (common base) transistors before the load resistors. This reduces the Miller Multiplication to 2X or less.

Notice the emitter linearization resistor in the diffpair; these 2 resistors greatly expand the "linear response region" of the diffpair and allow a better control over Slewing region behavior, permitting faster settling.

What does this tell us? That the high_frequency differential input capacitance of OpAmps **WILL VARY**, determined by the region of operation.

The ESD protection structures/diodes may or may not dominate.

During Slewing, the input capacitance will be **DIFFERENT** from small_signal input capacitance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the functioning of op-amps is very dependent on the differential impedance being significantly less than the common mode impedance, so I don't think it's that they are the same.

Perhaps the side to side values are the two impedances. Where it lists 50 and 300, perhaps that's differential 50k ohms and common mode 300k ohms.

Comment: No, the side-by-side values are "minimum" and "typical"